# X509 certificate CSR DN parsing

Tags: java, x509certificate, pki, x509

I'm having a problem with X.509 certificate DN parsing. The CSR generated is of the form:

/C=/ST=/L=/O=/OU=/CN=

The signed certificate issued by the CA is of the form:

C=USA, ST=NJ, L=test, O=Google, OU=Adwords, CN=test

I need a utility class in Java, preferably something standard that will take either of these notations and canonicalize the DN to a standard format so I can compare the CSR and X.509 certificate data to determine if the DN's match.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parsing the X509 Certificate issued by the CA, you can use the following java api:
*[java.security.cert.X509Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html)*

Code snippet:

```
    extractX509DN(X509Certificate cert) {
        String domainName;
        domainName = cert.getSubjectDN().getName();
    }
```

Likewise, you can use the other methods in the api to extract details of the certificate you need.

For parsing the raw CSR, you can use the apis provided by [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html). I found a handy tutorial which you could probably use to understand the method involved in parsing a CSR:

*[Parse CSR Code Snippet](http://code.google.com/p/eid-pki-ra/source/browse/trunk/eid-pki-ra-util-crypto/src/main/java/be/fedict/eid/pkira/crypto/CSRParserImpl.java?r=91)*

Go through the above link and understand the following function:

```
    public CSRInfo parseCSR (String csr);
```

Your answer lies in line number 76 of the above code snippet.